# How data and memory affects execution speed?

Tags: performance

If my application is allotted 500MB of RAM, but operates on 2GB of data, how will this work?  What would be the impact on execution speed?

Comment: Depends on the environment. Some environments will just give you an out of memory error, others will use paging, or your framework may just stream it to keep within the 500MB allocation. Either way, if it is working, you are adding overhead to the process and will see a decrease in available resources for sure.

Comment: It will work as well as your question (with comparable performance), which needs around 100 words to be effective but has only been allotted 26.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know - depends on what you're doing and how your application operates on data.

You can't fit 10 pounds of anything into a 5 pound bag.  You'll have to page or operate on a stream or something.

If you exhaust the memory available to you, you're likely to see an OutOfMemoryError.

Not enough information to give a real answer.

Comment: you can fit 10 pounds of gold into a 5 pound bird feed bag...lol. I get the point though...2GB of data has to be handled by 500MB of RAM differently than 500MB of data would be.

Comment: Which weighs more - a pound of gold or a pound of bird seed?  I think we agree, Watermark Studios.

Answer (score 1):

Every time it needed to access data that is outside the current 500 megabyte window, it would need to swap out to disk.  That swapping process takes some time, depending on disk speed, and would potentially slow down your application.